# Is it possible to access Excel file through ADO.NET that does NOT have a Header Row?

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I have a formated Excel file, over which I do not have control, and I need to read the information contained in it.

The problem with the file is that the first few rows contain formated information and I can not modify that file nor I can not ask for a format change.

Is it possible then, to read such a file through ADO.Net?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this article explains how to do this pretty well:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934

As for the lack of a header row...

> With Excel workbooks, the first row in
>   a range is the header row (or field
>   names) by default. If the first range
>   does not contain headers, you can
>   specify HDR=NO in the extended
>   properties in your connection string.
>   If you specify HDR=NO in the
>   connection string, the Jet OLE DB
>   provider automatically names the
>   fields for you (F1 represents the
>   first field, F2 represents the second
>   field, and so on).